# Basic Key Logger - Code Not Working

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
Dim KeyState

Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Int32) As Boolean

Private Sub LogTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LogTimer.Tick
    For I = 1 To 255
        KeyState = 0

        KeyState = GetAsyncKeyState(I)
        If KeyState = True Then
            Me.txtLog.Text = Me.txtLog.Text & Chr(I)
        End If

    Next I
End Sub
End Class
```

---

Just a run down:
I am attempting to get the up/down state of every key every tenth of a second(the timer), then add any keys pressed to a textbox.

I honestly cannot see why this code is not working.

Comment: It doesn't return Boolean, it returns Short.  The key is down if the return value is negative.  A virtual key, not a character.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you actually have the timer being told to start somewhere. In my experience, I've always had to write actual code to tell it start, and the properties in design view always give me trouble.